# What is the point of finding a limit? Does limit give us a real/exact value?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I wonder whether limit gives us an exact value. I mean look at this example:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2}$$ 
is 4 , right?

But what if we do not use limit. Obviously at $x = 2$, it would be undefined.
So when x is approaching 2 we can say $f(x)$ is approaching 4. But when x is 2, we can not say it is 4, am I right?

Then, what is the point in finding limit? Isn't it like you just "play" around a thing but not at the thing itself, no matter how close you are to the thing. Doesn't it feel like it is not real, not exact, or not concrete?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0} f(x)$ tells us how the function behaves "near" $x_0$, but it doesn't tell us anything about $f(x_0)$, which might not even exist

Comment: The limit is exact in the sense that, if $4$ is the limit, then $4.1$ is _not_ the limit, and neither is $4.001$, and neither is $4.0000001$… The limit is exactly $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the limit is equal to $4$ since
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 2}\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2} =\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}x+2 = 4$$

This means that $f(x)$ can be made to be as close to 4 as desired by making $x$ sufficiently close to $2$. This is despite the fact that $f(2)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that a car moves along a road such that, after $t$ s, it is at position $t^2$ m.

The average velocity between time $t=2$ s and time $t=x$ s is
$$\frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2}$$

The limit shows that, if we measure the velocity at a small interval starting in $t=2$ s, the result will be close to 4 m/s. We say that 4 m/s is the velocity of the car at that instant.

The concept of instant velocity is one example of an application of limits.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly exact; it's just not necessarily answering the question you *want* it to answer.

You're right that "$\lim_{x\rightarrow c}f(x)=L$" tells us nothing about $f(c)$, even whether $f(c)$ is defined. However, that's not the only use limits have!

**Example.** Consider the parabola $f(x)=x^2$. At every point $(a, a^2)$ on the parabola, there is exactly one (non-vertical) line passing through $(a, a^2)$ and *no other* point on the parabola; this is the *tangent line*.$^*$ Via limits, we can find an *exact* expression for the tangent line through $(a, a^2)$ - it's $y=2ax-a^2$.

This is a nice example because we can prove, after the fact, that this line does in fact meet the parabola in exactly one point, and that it's the only (non-vertical) line through $(a, a^2)$ which does so. Moreover, the limit approach lets us calculate tangent lines to a huge variety of curves.

This is *by far* not the only example, but I think it's the most elementary one.

---

$^*$This isn't really the right way to define "tangent line", even for very nice functions; but it works here.

Comment: The tangent line definition does not work here either. Any vertical line passes through exactly one point of the parabola. (You could consider the projective plane and points at infinity, but that is another story.)

Comment: @filipos Derp, in my head I was talking about *linear functions* :P. Fixed!

Comment: Alternatively, there is only one line passing through $(a, a^2)$ such that the parabola is *entirely on one side* of the line.

Answer (score 1):

For your first and second questions: yes (as already said in the other answers). Let me consider the other question:

*What is the point of finding a limit?*

Look at the picture below.

[image]

Intuitively speaking, to $f$ be continuous at $2$ what should be the value of $f(2)$? Well, since $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $4$ as $x$ moves closer and closer to $2$, it should be $4$ which is $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)$.

This happens in general: $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ (if it exists) gives the value that $f$ should attains at $c$ in order to $f$ be continuous at $c$ (which is a real, exact and concrete thing, right?)

*Remark:* If such limit doesn't exist, it's not possible to make $f$ continuous at $c$ by defining (or redefining) the value of $f$ at $c$.